# How can I use CONS in reverse way?

Tags: scheme, racket, cons

Normally, we pass two arguments to `cons`, in RACKET

`eg:`
`(cons 23 '(1 2 3))`

which outputs `'(23 1 2 3)`

Is there any procedure to do the following

`(procedure '(1 2 3)  23)` => `'(1 2 3 23)`

Comment: @Rptx thanks for the solution...but the solution gives a `pair` 
@Oscar solution is correct which creates list. Both  the arguments passed to append should be `list` then onlly it will work
else it gives a pair.
`eg:` `(append '(1 23) 23)` => `'(1 23 .23)` //pair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(append '(1 2 3) '(23))
=> '(1 2 3 23)
```

That's fine for appending a single element. If you're planning to repeatedly add many elements at the end, it's better if you `cons` everything at the head and then `reverse` the list when you're done. Why? because using `append` for building an output list will quickly degenerate into an `O(n^2)` solution (see: [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm))

Comment: (cons 23 '(1 2 3) would result in '(23 1 2 3). Inverting this would result in '(3 2 1 23) which is not quite the desired result. So simply "cons-ing" everything and inverting at the end won't do, I guess?

Comment: You'd start `cons`ing from the beginning, and then invert: `(reverse (cons 23 (cons 3 (cons 2 (cons 1 '())))))` .

Comment: I often see this named `snoc` (`cons` backwards): `(define (snoc x xs) (append xs (list x)))`.

Comment: And if the reverse at the end isn't and option or you are reversing your list a lot, it's probably a sign you need a more complex data structure than the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

In Lisp/Scheme/Racket if you want a procedure, writing it makes it largely indistinguishable from built in procedures:

```
#lang racket

(define (procedure a-list an-atom)
  (cond
    [(not (list? a-list)) (error "procedure: first argument not a list")]
    [(pair? an-atom) (error "procedure: second argument is a list")]
    [else
     (append a-list (list an-atom))]))
```

Then use it:

```
> (procedure '(1 2 3) 23)
'(1 2 3 23)
```